# react-native-image-zoom-viewer library not working as per expectation for image zoom in release build

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-image-zoom-viewer for zooming of images when images are clicked in a carousal. The image zoom functionality works fine when the app is running in debug mode. But when i am trying to test this same functionality in release mode, it's not working as expectation.

I am passing props for initial view of the image as 300*300 (height*width), that runs fine on debug mode. But in release mode, the same doesn't work and i think new image size becomes 800*800 but i am never passing any-kind of values like that.

I have already tried by passing proper props as suggested by library as per its document. Did some alterations too. But nothing seems working on debug mode

```
const imageList = [];
            for (let i=0; i<images.length; i++){
                imageList.push({url:images[i].uri,width:300,height:300});
            }
            return(
                <ImageViewerLib 
                    imageUrls={imageList}
                    renderIndicator={()=>{}}
                    loadingRender={()=><Loader isLoader = { true } style = {{height:100,with:100}} />}
                    renderArrowLeft={()=>
                        <View style={{padding: 10}} >
                            <Icon 
                                type = { 'Ionicons' } 
                                name = { 'arrow-round-back' }
                            />
                        </View>
                    }
                    renderArrowRight={()=>
                        <View style={{padding: 10}}>
                            <Icon 
                                type = { 'Ionicons' } 
                                name = { 'arrow-round-forward' }
                            />
                        </View>
                    }
                    backgroundColor="white"
                    index={imageIndex}
                    saveToLocalByLongPress={false}
                    enablePreload={true}
                    flipThreshold={50}
                    maxOverflow={300}
                />
            );
```

As you can see in the above code that i am passing fixed image width and height which works smoothly in debug mode.
But when in release mode, this size doesn't work. Initial rendered image is much lager that above provided dimension.

Comment: Do you find a solution or alternative? I have some problems with that library too.

Comment: pass additional props of resizeMode and it will render accordingly